# Error 400 when Creating Custom Classifier in Watson Visual Recognition

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, visual-recognition

I am currently facing a problem to create my own classfiers. I already tried to build a NodeJS application and also create it using [IBM's demo](http://visual-recognition-tooling.mybluemix.net/), but everytime I submit my ZIP folders to be created, I recieve the following error message:

```
Cannot execute learning task.  : need at least 2 _positive_examples fields,  (or 1 _positive_examples and 1 negative_examples field) to train a classifier. null specified.
```

However, when I tried to use the IBM Demo webapp using the .zip they provide (husky, beagle and cats.zip files) the classifier is successfully createdi

I have currently 2 zips (1 positive and 1 negative) each containing 50 files named from 1.jpg to 50.jpg.

Have any of you guys ever gone through this issue and found a way to handle it?

Thanks for the attention.

Best regards,
Enrico Bergamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the discussion on the DeveloperWorks Forum ( https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/377690/error-400-when-trying-to-create-a-custom-classifie/ ), Your zip files are not really zips. It looks like all you have done is name your folder positive.zip.

Right click on each of the folders in turn and select create zip or compress as zip.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! I have tried before placing the images at the root level inside the zip, but it didn't work so I decided to follow IBM's example. Now I decided to recreate my zips inside a Linux environment.. I'm not really sure if it has anything to do with it, but it works and I'm really thankful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What this message indicates is that the service is not receiving any POST fields that end in '_positive_examples' which is necessary for a training request.  So double check your form field name parameters.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for the response! I didn't know I had to use the '_positive_examples' suffix. Nevertheless, I've tried the following POST and still received the same error message: `curl -X POST -F "rg_positive_examples=@positive.zip" -F "husky_positive_examples=@positive.zip" -F "negative_examples=@negative.zip" -F "name=docs" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers?api_key={xyz}&version=2016-05-20"`

Comment: It appears that you are sending the same file, positive.zip for both class definitions, but the system requires at least 10 unique examples in each